# SKNode to stop at exact position after applyImpulse

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision

The `ball.physicsBody` is set as below to allow it to bounce infinitely inside `SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)`.

```
ball.physicsBody?.friction = 0
ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
ball.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
```

To make it bounce, I use `applyImpulse`.

```
ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(vector)
```

[image]

I want to the ball to land on a platform (as shown in the screenshot) without bouncing back.

I have tried to set its `restitution = 0` and `velocity = .zero` when it contacts with the platform inside `didBegin(_:)`. But it always bounces back if the velocity is high. It touches the bottom frame if it is not set to collide with the platform.

I wonder if anyone can provide a code snippet to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: Removing the physics body should stop it I suppose.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it doesn't land on the platform. It's randomly due to the velocity and frame rate. :(

Comment: You could add logic to the collision (between the ball and platform) and set the velocity of the ball to 0 after the collision is detected.

Comment: @RandyRakestraw did you mean `didBegin(_:)`? I already did that and that only work for slow velocity.

Comment: I would say changing physics body to static would work... But I would need a MVP to tell more. I mean you can do some corrections as well, after contact is detected, or to try to set collision bit mask and velocity to 0, as suggested...

Comment: What if you just pause the ball as soon as it contacts?

Comment: What is your platform?  Make sure that is set to dynamic = false

Comment: I checked `contact.contactPoint`, and I now understand why the ball doesn't land on the platform in the case of high velocity. It's because the `didBegin(_:)` is call and the `contactPoint` is set after the ball bounds.

Comment: Which is the platform physics? Is setted platform.restitution = 0 on it? Did you try to set show physics = false end run it on  devices instead the simulator?